# Immutable record to clone self when saving changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I want to have a model that, if I make changes to it and save, it will be saved as a new record. This is like the idea of immutable strings. I am wondering if there are existing gem/tutorials/best practice covering this area?

Most gems I have looked at simply stop you from doing any modification. However I want to modify, just that modifications are saved into the copy of the record. Theoretically this should cover any means of update in Rails such as `update_attributes`, and `save` should also return the new copy of record.

Comment: You want to have a kind of update history in your app? If so have a look at paper_trail gem, https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail

Comment: @rmagnum2002 no not really. I want to make existing associations unaffected, meaning that I want to keep existing record unaffected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So at the end I put the following into my model.

To go the easy way, I block access to build-in save functions by making it readonly.

Then I have a method for saving modifications. A copy will be saved, but it will update selected references to it. For example, when I update a price object, I also update existing product using that price to point to the new price record. While orders will still refer to the old record.

```
  def readonly?
    persisted?
  end

  def save_as_clone
      return self if ! changed?

      copy = self.dup
      ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
        copy.save!
        if copy.persisted?
          # Update existing references
          self.products.update_all(price_id:copy.id)
        end
      end
      copy
  end

  def destroy
    # remove mapping only but do not destroy self
  end

  def delete
    # remove mapping only but do not destroy self
  end
```

I guess I can make it more implicit by overriding the save/save!/update_attributes methods. However since this is not normal behaviour I chose to be explicit and stop here. If anyone has a more general solution please also post that.

Answer (score 0):

You probably can make use of rails `changed?` method. An example based on `User` model:

```
def update
  @object = YourClass.find(params[:id])

  if @object.changed?
    # Create new object
  else
    # Action if no change has been made
  end
end
```

the `changed?` method will check if any attributes of your model has been changed, of you want to specify an exact attribute you'll use `object.attributename_changed?`:

```
[10] pry(main)> u = User.last
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."type" IN ('User', 'AnonymousUser', 'DeletedUser') ORDER BY "users"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
=> #<User id: 5, login: "Carson725", firstname: "Hillard", lastname: "VonRueden">
[11] pry(main)> u.lastname = 'Someother'
=> "Sergiu"
[12] pry(main)> u.changed?
=> true
[13] pry(main)> u.firstname_changed?
=> false
[14] pry(main)> u.lastname_changed?
=> true
[15] pry(main)>
```

**ruby 2.1.5p273 / Rails 3.2.21**

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html

Comment: thanks, but it would be nicer if the solution is implemented at the ActiveModel level instead of the controller level

Comment: Agree, it would be.. :) Might be some other SO user will share a better idea. Would like to know it myself.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't heard about the specific task gems, but in earlier Rails there was readonly record, and the attempt to update of which was refised with exception. In modern versions of Rails that kinds of record was deprecated, and no there is just readonly attributes that can be set for relations. But you could create a model that will refuse to update the records, but in a controller you can catch that specific exception and try to create a new record based on the refused one, like follows:

```
class ReadonlyModelException < ActiveRecord::ActiveRecordError; end

class ReadonlyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
   before_update { |_| raise ReadonlyModelException }
end

class User < ReadonlyModel; end
```

in a controller just trap the exception and change behaviour.

```
def update
   user = User.where(id: params[:id]).first
   user.update_attributes(name: "New name") # => ReadonlyModelException
rescue ReadonlyModelException
   redirect :create
end
```

**NOTE**: But the better approach in my vision is to not use the `#update` action for the specific pair model/controller, and only `#new/#create` pair.